# Setting up Git to fetch all remote branches

Tags: git

I somehow ended up with a git configuration with the following in the [remote] section:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This of course means that I would never ever see branches that my collaborators have added. I realize that I need to change this to:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

but I am confused as to why my configuration ended up this way in the first place, and more importantly, how I can avoid it ever happening again. Any idea how to set up a repo so that it does not do this?

Thanks,
cf

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you used `git remote add -t master origin url/to/origin/.git`. The `-t master` switch overrides the `fetch` refspec to only fetch that one branch. If you skip the `-t master` then you'll get the expected glob refspec.